# Настройка общения сервер-клиент на Rust

Tags: клиент-сервер, rust

Хочу сделать эмуляцию сервер-клиент по TCP/IP, надеюсь я правильно выразился, поправьте меня, если ошибка.

1. Как сделать loop, чтоб программа сервера ожидала запроса от клиента бесконечно?
   Я предпологаю, что это похоже на GameLoop.
2. Как сделать простой запрос из клиента на этот сервер?
3. Как сделать обработку запроса на сервере, полученную от клиента?

Я без опыта в этой сфере, прошу отвечать подробнее, спасибо вам заранее :)

Comment: Нет, на GameLoop сетевой цикл похож не сильно. Главное отличие - в отличии от игрового, он никогда не должен "крутиться" вхолостую.

Comment: Читай вы книгу, знали бы https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html

Comment: Нет, мне не нужен веб сервер. Я хочу обычный TCP/IP Server Client

Comment: @VyacheslavOdinokov что имеется ввиду под эмуляцией? Это значит что нужен код, который будет запускать и клиент и сервер и имитировать их удаленное взаимодействие, или я не так понял?